# An extremely basic question about statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, measure-theory

We do statistics on data which we assume to be outcome of random trials. The question however, is -- are we assuming that the outcome can be represented as a random variable?

The outcome of an experiment is representable as a random variable if that function is measurable. If the mapping from the event space, to the set of real numbers, is a measurable function, then we can even think of assigning a probability to that random variable.

Thought experiments are fine. We can assume that the outcome of a thought experiment, like rolling a dice, has an outcome that can be represented by a measurable function which we designate as the random variable.

When dealing with real data, don't we ***assume*** that the process that generates that data, can be represented as a random variable? Is that simply an assumption, or are there concrete reasons/tests to believe that it is indeed measurable?

Comment: Are you confusing "measurable" in colloquial with measurable mathematically? Measurable is a mathematical definition and not your belief.

Comment: Data generation "processes" aren't measurable, but random variables are.  Measurability becomes an issue when modeling stochastic processes in continuous time, where it is related to what kinds of variables can be well-defined and given meaningful properties.  As in any field of applied mathematics, a model is used to reason about the data and a theory. There no reason to put it on some elevated ontological plane to be worshiped as "real" or denigrated as "simply an assumption."

Comment: @whuber All I wanted to ask was how do we even assume that a certain process  has a probability distribution? A random variable is a "measurable function" from the sample space to a measurable space. I am aware that there are tests to check if the data is normally distributed (the normality tests) but how do you even test for something as basic as whether the given data set can be represented as realizations of a "random variable"? For all we know, the mapping from an event space to a measurable space, if it exists for that process, may not be a  measurable function right?

Comment: @Germania In statistics, there is a dataset and they are usually assumed to be realizations of a certain distribution. For the dataset to be realizations of a certain random variable, there must be a corresponding set function that is measurable to begin with. That such a measurable set function even exists must then be an assumption correct? What is the basis? I mean you can define whatever you want but then, to use it in practice, there must be a basis. What is that basis?

Comment: The map is not the territory and the model is not the reality. The formal construct of observations as realisations of a random variable is used for prediction or explanation purposes, it does not imply a belief that it is real. Take for instance the SIER modelling of COVID propagation, a useful if artificial representation of the real thing.

Comment: @Xi'an "it does not imply a belief that it is real ..." which, put in other words, implies that we are indeed assuming the existence of the random variable and hence, we assume that it has a cdf. Maybe I was not articulate enough when I asked the question because of which I did not get a convincing answer before you commented. Basically you have confirmed what I had suspected as being true. Thanks!

Comment: "Bernardo and Smith (2000) define M-closed problems as those for which a true model can be identified and written down but is one amongst finitely many models from which an analyst has to choose. By contrast, M-complete problems are those in which a true model (sometimes called a belief model) exists but is inaccessible in the sense that even though it can be conceptualized it cannot be written down or at least cannot be used directly. Effectively this means that other surrogate models must be identified and used for inferential purposes." Le & Clarke (2017)

Comment: "M-open problems according to Bernardo and Smith are those problems where a true model exists but cannot be specified at all." [Le & Clarke, 2017](https://doi.org/10.1214/16-BA1023)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136782/discussion-between-tryinghardtobecomeagoodprslvr-and-xian).